# Checkbox update page (show more info if checked)

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to figure out how to list 3 check-boxes at the top of a page that, when checked, auto reveal more info on the page.

Using php if I can hide the info, but how will it update page? I am guessing some form of java.

Comment: you need to come at this with javascript.

Comment: You mean JavaScript, not Java. Those are two completely different things that share nothing but 4 characters of the name and the fact that both are languages with a curly-braces syntax.

Comment: gotcha. So which one will not work on ipads, ipods?

Answer (score 0):

you need JavaScript - http://jsfiddle.net/JQRG7/

and you don't have to hide your content with PHP, you can do it with CSS. However if you really don't want to have that additional info on your page(if page size an issue, for example) then you have to use Ajax to load it.

Comment: Works, one more request, when unchecked, disappears. Default checked

Comment: change `$("#c" + index).show();` to `$("#c" + index).toggle();` - http://jsfiddle.net/JQRG7/1/